# Using DROP CONSTRAINT to remove a UNIQUE key instead of drop index in mariaDB

Tags: mariadb, unique-constraint

Is it possible to use DROP CONSTRAINT to eliminate a UNIQUE key instead of drop index in mariaDB?
For example:
ALTER TABLE `c_docs` DROP CONSTRAINT cid_type;
Instead of
ALTER TABLE `c_docs` DROP INDEX cid_type;
Or we should always use DROP INDEX to remove the UNIQUE key?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would say "try it" rather than asking the question.

I suspect it won't work, so here is a 'perfect' workaround:

```
ALTER TABLE c_docs
    DROP INDEX cid_type,
    ADD  INDEX cid_type(cid_type);  -- (or whatever column(s) there are)
```

That will atomically do what you desire.

Comment: As I have mentioned I know the DROP INDEX way of doing it and that is not my question. About using DROP CONSTRAINT I did try it (why did you assume that I hadn't) and it did not work. But as it is expressed in the documentation that it is possible to use DROP CONSTRAINT to remove constraints I guess there may be a right way of doing it using constraint.

Comment: May I get snippy back at you?  You did not say that you tried it.  You did not show that you would put both steps in a single `ALTER`, which I did show.  Meanwhile, I will _guess_ that the documentation was thinking about constraints such as `FOREIGN KEYs` when it suggested `DROP CONSTRAINT`.  Feel free to complain about the doc on dropping a uniqueness constraint:  bugs.mysql.com .